# Why can't I apply transformations to a function in a linear way?

Tags: functions

> Suppose $f(4)=8$. Note that the point $(2,8)$ is on the graph of
>   $y=f(2x)$ and that the point $(5,8)$ is on the graph of $y=f(2x-6)$.
>   So,the point we have found on the graph of $y=f(2x-6)$ is $3$ units to
>   the right of the point we found on the graph of $y=f(2x)$.Which of the
>   following is true :$(a)$we made a mistake;$(b)$it's a coincidence-not
>   every point on $y=f(2x-6)$ is $3$ to the right of a point on
>   $y=f(2x)$;$(c)$ the graph of $y=f(2x-6)$ is a $3$-unit rightward shift
>   of the graph of $y=f(2x)$.Explain your answer

I  am really confused about this exercise of my book.

I've previously learned that for every function $y=f(x)$ the transformed version $y=f(x-k)$ corresponds to a shift of  $k$ units rightward of $y=f(x)$ and that $y=f(kx)$ is a horizontal scaling of a factor of $\cfrac{1}{k}$ of $y=f(x)$.

> **When I apply linearly the transformations :**

If I am to apply this informations  I would have that  if $f(4)=8$ is a point on my function $y=f(x)$ then $(2,8)$ is a point on the function $y=f(2x)$ then if I shift this new function by $6$ units rightward I have $y=f(2x-6)$ so the point $(2,8)$ maps to $(2+6,8)$ but this is wrong.

> **When I don't apply transformations linearly I get the right answer**

Now if I reason as follows I have the right answer: since $(4,8)$ is a point on my original function which gets then transformed to $y=f(2x-6)$ I have that if I want to have $f(4)$ on my transformed function I have $2x-6=4$ $\implies x=5$ which gets me the point $(5,8)$.

In general if I have the point $(a,f(a))$ this gets mapped to the point$(\cfrac{a}{2}+3,f(a))$ in the function $y=f(2x-6)$ which is a $3$ units rightward shift of $y=f(2x)$.

**Question**

But why didn't I get the correct answer by applying linearly the transformations as in first case ?

Does this mean that I can't apply transformations linearly to a function as this would lead me to the wrong answer (perhaps because by doing so I am considering different functions each time ?) ?

Can someone make this clear to me ?

Comment: My post is a little rambling ...if someone wants to edit ,he is welcome-

Comment: Replacing $x$ with $x-k$ corresponds to shifting the graph rightward by $k$. But you didn't have $f(x)$, you had $f(2x)$. So shifting rightward by $6$ would be $f(2(x-6))$, not $f(2x-6)$. Now can you figure out what shift would give you the desired $f(2x-6)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make a simple mistake: Let’s first horizontal scale $f$ by the factor $2$, i.e. consider the function $g(x) = f(2x)$. If we now shift this new function $g$ by $6$ units to the right, we get a new function $h(x) = g(x-6)$. But now observe that
$$
 h(x) = g(x-6) = f(2(x-6)) = f(2x-12).
$$
What you ignored is that the scaling and the shifting don’t commute: It is important in which order we scale and shift, because scaling also affects the shifting distance.

This may be a bit confusing if you are not used to this, because if we first scale $f$ by $2$ and then shift the resulting function by $6$ to the right, arriving at a new function $h$, then to evaluate $h(x)$ you have to apply the operations to $x$ in the *reversed* order, i.e. you first shift $x$ by $6$ and get $x-6$ and then multiply the result by $2$ and get $2(x-6) = 2x-12$.

It may be helpful to visualize this as follows:
$$
 (\mathrm{shift}(\mathrm{scale}(f)))(x)
= (\mathrm{scale}(f))(\mathrm{shift}(x))
= f(\mathrm{scale}(\mathrm{shift}(x))).
$$

Comment: My bad, you’re right. I fixed it.